# ¿Por qué se visualizan diferentes las mismas fuentes?

Tags: css, css3, google-chrome, fuentes

Les vengo a comentar algo muy raro que me sucede, resulta que estoy haciendo una remodelación de una web, antes usaba las fonts llamándolas por su nombre y no por su weight, por ejemplo:

```css
font-family: 'Open Sans Bold';
```

En lugar de

```css
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-weight: 700;
```

Pero resulta que sorpresa, a la hora de implementar mis nuevos cambios para mejorar a nivel de código y de performance, obtengo que la misma weight, tiene diferentes formas, en el mismo navegador, solo que con mi implementación se ve diferente.

Ya intenté con muchas propiedades para el renderizado correcto:

```css
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

Evidentemente, el problema no era ese, encontré el problema. Cuando usamos Open Sans regular, a su vez viene incluida dentro de sí, una weight 700 AUNQUE NO ESTÉ DECLARADA EN EL FONT-FACE, y es diferente a la fuente de "Open Sans Bold", si cargamos la "Open Sans Regular" y a su vez usamos:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Vamos a ver una fuente bold weight, pero no es realmente la original "Open Sans Bold", si se descargan la "Open Sans Bold" van a ver que hay diferencia entre poner:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFUZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFW50bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

```css
font-family: 'Open Sans'; // Esta NO incluye la font-weight bold, en teoría, pero si lo hace más oscuro
font-weight: bold;
```

Resultados:

[image]

***Y PONER***

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFUZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFW50bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOX-hpOqc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOVuhpOqc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOXuhpOqc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOUehpOqc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOXehpOqc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOXOhpOqc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOUuhp.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

```css
font-family: 'Open Sans'; // Esta incluye en su font-face la weight 700
font-weight: bold;
```

Resultados:

[image]

La segunda es más "negrita" que la fuente regular, en efecto, pero necesito usar la "negrita" que incluye la Regular y la negrita ORIGINAL, es decir "Open Sans Bold", ambas en el mismo sitio. Alguien sabe por qué ocurre este comportamiento tan extraño? A alguien se le ocurre alguna solución a este problema? Yo le vengo dando vueltas hace 2 días, y nada, no consigo llegar a puerto. Gracias de antemano.

PD: NO estoy usando la API de google fonts, solo la uso para ejemplificar, pero si descargue la open sans desde el sitio de google (también de otros sitios, y el mismo problema)

Comment: Para mejorar la explicación de el porque ocurre eso podrías añadir como se declaran las ```@font-face``` mediante CSS, ya que también sirve para hacer tu propia fuente personalizada. Si vas a la misma url que te pone el link aparece las font-face declaradas [fuente](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap)

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias, ahí puse los font-faces

Comment: Podrías probrar declarando en tu `embed` el link _customizado_ que te ofrece Google Fonts directamente, usando una sóla hoja de estilos para la fuente así: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: El tutorial va de "porque pasa", simplemente lo de las ```@font-face``` es por el comentario de ```AUNQUE NO ESTÉ DECLARADA EN EL FONT-FACE```, simplemente están declaradas. Pero el CSS las diferencias si pones por ejemplo ```font-style:bold``` por ejemplo. Aunque tiene el mismo nombre de font-face

Comment: @matahombres No me di a entender, cuando cargas una fuente, en un `@font-face` que solo contenga un font-weight: 400, es decir que solo cargues la fuente en su forma REGULAR, no debería de cargar ninguna otro "grosor" de fuente, es decir que si solo tengo regular, y pongo font-weight: 900. Debería seguir la font-weight:400, porque no hay nada declarado, no es un problema tan simple como parece, no es un error en la declaración de las fuentes ni un error mío de cómo las llamo, si solo cargo open sans regular, y pongo 700 se me pone bold, pero no el mismo que la bold, y no debería cargar bold

Comment: Oh, pues es cierto... Vaya, vaya